# can't find source file when debug in x86

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I put an .h source file in the additional dependency folder, and add its location to the C++ additional include directories.  But when I debug under x86, the .h file can't be found. When debugging under x64, there's no problem. why?

Comment: If the file belongs to you / your project (not a library header file), better add it directly to your sources.

Comment: You should also place that header file in additional dependency folder for x64 configuration too. If you want both x86 and x64 to use the same dependency folder then in the 'Property Pages' dialog box, set configuration to All and then add it's location again

Comment: yes it works, I haven't noticed that x86 and x64 should be set desperately thank you very much!!